# how to stop a form from submitting without disable the button with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, http-post

hello I have a simple form to validate I want to do a client side validation lets say that my form has only one field for name I want to check if the name length is between 5 and 20 chars if yes then no problem and the data will be sent to the server and then apply a server side validation ;however, if it's not then an error message will be displayed in a span beside the input field says that it must be 5 to 20 chars.The problem is when I hit the submit button it shows the result for less than a second then it goes cause the submit button reload the page which also means if I have included my server side validation it will also be processed since the input data already sent so how can I stop the submit button from sending data to the server and reloading the page without disabling the button.

here is my example code

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
<head>
    <title>form validation</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function(){
               myfunction();
            });

            function myfunction()
            {
                name = $("#user").val();
                nameError = $(".error").first();
                myError = "";
                if(name.length < 5 || name.length > 20)
                    myError += "length should be between 5 and 20 ";
                else
                    myError += "ok"

                nameError.html(myError);

            }
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        .error
        {
            color : red;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" action="">
        NAME : <input type="text" name="user" id="user"><span class="error"></span><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: return true /false from "myfunction" and check on button like   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="return myfunction();">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're not canceling form submission on finding a problem.

To do this you'll need to listen for a submission event on the form, not a click event on the button.

Try:

```
       $("form").on('submit', myfunction); //<-- listen for form submit, not button click

        function myfunction(evt) { //<-- the event object is automatically passed along;
                                   //    this is key for suppressing submission
            name = $("#user").val();
            nameError = $(".error").first();
            myError = "";
            if(name.length < 5 || name.length > 20)
                myError += "length should be between 5 and 20 ";
            else
                myError += "ok"

            if (myError) {
                evt.preventDefault(); //<-- suppress submission if error found
                nameError.html(myError);
            }

        }
```

You could alternatively use [HTML5 validation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/constraintvalidation/) and make your life a little easier.

Comment: Thanks a lot appreciate your help btw the evt.preventDefault() will also prevent that data from being sent to the server right ?

Comment: I have this as a server side validation for example and after I got two ok on my form it won't run this php validation why 

<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $name = $_POST['user'];
        
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
             echo "name must contain only characters";   
           else
             echo "thanks for submitting the form";
           
  
    }
?>

Comment: It will prevent data being sent to the server - i.e. form submission - ONLY if there is an error. If not, the form will be submitted.

Comment: I tried again still giving me just ok but the php result won't show I also updated the action in the form if you wondered please help

Comment: The PHP will take effect only if the form is submitted. Do you mean the form is being submitted but the PHP still doesn't take effect?

Comment: Yes exactly this is what I mean

Comment: Sorry, that's beyond the scope of this question. It's not about your PHP - it's about form submission. If you have a separate problem with PHP (any errors? Sure the script is being executed? Etc) please post a separate question specifically about that.

Comment: I already did that, the problem was if there is an error it will set the myerror variablie to the error string else it will set it to "ok" and in the if statement is said if(myError)  which will always be true so I have to change the condition to if(myError != "ok") that is the problem thanks anyway

Comment: `if (myError)` will not always be true in the code I gave you because its initial value was `""`. An empty value evaluates to falsy, i.e. will not pass the condition `if (myError)`. But your way is also fine.

Comment: Yeah I get your idea it's simpler but I think if I give the user a message telling him it's ok so he can know then that this field is right that's why I did that 

Answer (score 2):

Just do one thing .It is very easy.Follow my code.There is no need of javascript or jQuery.Code is tested on my Pc.Hope will enjoy.

---

```
<form method="post" action="" >
  NAME : <input type="text" name="user" pattern="[A-Z a-z.]{5,20}" title="Enter your name between 5 and 20 charecters" required="required" accesskey="U"/><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#submit").click(function(){
     if ($('#user').text.length > 4 ){
           myfunction();
    }else{
    // show error message
    }
});
```

try this, do validate on click not in the function

Comment: This won't cancel the form submission.

Comment: ok.. add (e) as function parameter, and place on else - e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one..



<!doctype html>
     <html>
    <head>
        <title>form validation</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {


                function myfunction()
                {
                    name = $("#user").val();
                    nameError = $(".error").first();
                    myError = "";
                    if(name.length < 5 || name.length > 20){
                        myError += "length should be between 5 and 20 ";
                        return false;
                    }
                    else{
                        myError += "ok"

                    nameError.html(myError);
                     return true;
                     }

                }
            });
        </script>

        <style>
            .error
            {
                color : red;
                text-transform: capitalize;
                margin-left: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method="post" action="" onSubmit="return myFunction();">
            NAME : <input type="text" name="user" id="user"><span class="error"></span><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```